# Почему из базы данных выводятся иероглифы?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Вопрос в следующем: почему-то из базы данных в phpmyadmin выводятся иероглифы. Кодировка в phpmyadmin стоит `cp1251_general_ci`, на странице index.php, куда выводится инфа, кодировка `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`, не могу понять в чём дело. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Скажите, а в иероглифах выводятся все буквы или только кириллица.

Comment: В иероглифах только русские слова

Comment: Английские тексты выводятся нормально

Comment: charset=utf-8

Comment: И что это значит? Сделать кодировку страницы UTF-8? Делал. Ничего не меняется. Из базы всё равно иероглифы выводятся. Хотя через phpMyAdmin смотрю, там текст на русском.

Comment: а в бд какая кодировка? поставь там utf-8 и на странице...

Comment: Делал. Сначала там стандартно стояла УТФ-8, а на странице 1251. Поменял на странице на УТФ-8, ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй в скрипте после соединения с базой данных прописать запрос:

```
set names cp1251;
или
set names utf-8;
```

Comment: Ты имел ввиду mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251"); ? Я уже нашёл в нете. Так работает.